# How do I copy an XMLList and keep the namespace?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, e4x

Is there a way to copy an XMLList and keep the namespace? It seems when I use the copy() method on an XMLList the namespace is being removed.

Code:

```
var xml:XML = <s:Label xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"><s:color>red</s:color>
        test level</s:Label>;

var elementsXMLList:XMLList = xml.elements();
trace(elementsXMLList.toXMLString()); // has namespaces

var elementsCopy:XMLList = elementsXMLList.copy();
trace(elementsCopy.toXMLString()); // does not have namespaces
```

elementsXMLList.toXMLString():

```
<s:color xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">red</s:color>
```

elementsCopy().toXMLString():

```
<color xmlns="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">red</color>
```

I need to be able to keep the namespace when I make the copy.

Comment: I don't see why not `var copy:XML = new XML(xml.toXMLString());`.

Comment: Btw, doing `copy()` on XML and not on XMLList retains the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

This must be because it is `s:Label` node that contains the namespace declaration. `xml.elements()` gets you a list of xml elements that are part of `s:Label`'s tree, so they do know their namespace. When you do `elements.copy()` though you get a separate list of XML elements that are no longer part of the tree that has `xmlns:s`.

I'd suggest that you copy the whole tree starting with `s:Label`, then get its elements, instead of doing it another way around.